# CSS rule implementation: 4 character indent on each paragraph line that overflows

Tags: html, css

I want to create a rule for my webpage for p.comment that

1. limit one line of text to 80 characters before overflowing to next line.
2. indent each line of text that overflows(beyond 80 characters per line.)

So far I have:

```
p.comment {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    width: 80ch;
    text-indent: 4ch;
}
```

The issue is that the code above only indents first line, but I want it not to indent the first line, but indent all the lines EXCEPT the  first line.

I tried to see solutions on Google but am struggling to formulate it. Searching "html indent overflow" or "html indent paragraph overflow" seems not to give me answers I can make sense of.

### Example

**Before** (special thanks to http://uncyclopedia.wikia.com/wiki/Wall_of_Text)

```
A wall of text is something that is frowned upon in most, actually virtually all Internet societies, including forums, chat boards, and Uncyclopedia. You should not make walls of text because it can get you banned anywhere unless it is a place that encourages walls of text. I highly doubt any place does support something so irritating and annoying, but anything can exist, but not really because unless you are in heaven then that can happen. But no one actually knows that was just a hypothesis, a lame one that is. Actually not really lame. You can create a wall of text supporting site, but you would be hated if you do that, so do not. But you can if you like, but I discourage that. Now on to the actual information of walls of texts. The wall of text was invented when the Internet was invented, but actually it was slow at that time. So whenever it became fast. But there would need to be some free or not free community for people, and that community would be able to have walls of text. But that community probably wouldn't have actually invented the wall of text.
```

**After**:

```
A wall of text is something that is frowned upon in most, actually virtually all
    Internet societies, including forums, chat boards, and Uncyclopedia. You 
    should not make walls of text because it can get you banned anywhere unless 
    it is a place that encourages walls of text. I highly doubt any place does
    support something so irritating and annoying, but anything can exist, but 
    not really because unless you are in heaven then that can happen. But no 
    one actually knows that was just a hypothesis, a lame one that is. 
    Actually not really lame. You can create a wall of text supporting site, but
    you would be hated if you do that, so do not. But you can if you like, but I
    discourage that. Now on to the actual information of walls of texts. 
    The wall of text was invented when the Internet was invented, but actually 
    it was slow at that time. So whenever it became fast. But there would need 
    to be some free or not free community for people, and that community would 
    be able to have walls of text. But that community probably wouldn't have 
    actually invented the wall of text.
```

The idea is that by limiting the paragraph length to 80 characters, and
forcing it to indent on each new line, I avoid doing work that would normally
be done through wrapping every single 80 character paragraph into its own
span, which quickly damages ability to read the actual code for the webpage.

Granted, ideally a paragraph should also just turn into a warning message such as "This paragraph is too long to be rendered" if it is longer than 4 lines, as this makes the paragraph unreadable to many people who get to the end of the line and forget what line they were on, but I don't think this is possible without JavaScript.

If the above IS possible without Javascript, i'd like to know how to do that as well.

Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Like this?

```css
p.comment {
    padding-top: 5px;
    padding-bottom: 5px;
    padding-left:4ch;
    border-left: 3px solid var(--color-comment);
    width: 80ch;
    taxt-align: start;
    text-indent: -4ch;       
}
```

```html
<p class="comment">
A wall of text is something that is frowned upon in most, actually virtually all Internet societies, including forums, chat boards, and Uncyclopedia. You should not make walls of text because it can get you banned anywhere unless it is a place that encourages walls of text. I highly doubt any place does support something so irritating and annoying, but anything can exist, but not really because unless you are in heaven then that can happen. But no one actually knows that was just a hypothesis, a lame one that is. Actually not really lame. You can create a wall of text supporting site, but you would be hated if you do that, so do not. But you can if you like, but I discourage that. Now on to the actual information of walls of texts. The wall of text was invented when the Internet was invented, but actually it was slow at that time. So whenever it became fast. But there would need to be some free or not free community for people, and that community would be able to have walls of text. But that community probably wouldn't have actually invented the wall of text.
</p>
```

Comment: Thanks, it's exactly what I wanted. Can you explain why -4ch though over 4ch? Seems a bit counter intuitive to me.

Comment: @Dmitry: The entire text block is indented 4ch, then the first line is "unindented" by -4ch.

Comment: I didn't notice your padding-left. If I understand correctly it applies to the whole paragraph rather than individual overflow splits. So everything including first line is indented, but then only the first line is un-indented... Feels a bit counter intuitive since I thought indent would indent each overflow as well. But it works!

Comment: Feel free to remove the unnecessary code, "border-left", "t*a*xt-align". Otherwise it's perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
text-indent: -4ch;
padding-left: 4ch;
```

```css
div{
  text-indent: -4ch;
  padding-left: 4ch;
}
```

```html
<div>
  A wall of text is something that is frowned upon in most, actually virtually all Internet societies, including forums, chat boards, and Uncyclopedia. You should not make walls of text because it can get you banned anywhere unless it is a place that encourages
  walls of text. I highly doubt any place does support something so irritating and annoying, but anything can exist, but not really because unless you are in heaven then that can happen. But no one actually knows that was just a hypothesis, a lame one
  that is. Actually not really lame. You can create a wall of text supporting site, but you would be hated if you do that, so do not. But you can if you like, but I discourage that. Now on to the actual information of walls of texts. The wall of text
  was invented when the Internet was invented, but actually it was slow at that time. So whenever it became fast. But there would need to be some free or not free community for people, and that community would be able to have walls of text. But that community
  probably wouldn't have actually invented the wall of text.
</div>
```

Comment: Why 2em over 4ch? Are they equivalent?

Comment: No No. 4ch is absolutely fine. I was just checking if negative indent works and as it did I just posted it without verifying. My mistake. Updated it.